# How to run logstash inside Spring and Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using Logstash to read the logs of an API created with Spring, and send them to Elasticsearch to work with them later with Kibana. Everything is working perfect, but the problem is that I only find a way to use Logstash outside my own project, but not inside Maven/Spring (in the same project I build where everything works together).

I want to avoid to have external processes that aren't part of the main Java application since Logstash should be always fetching the logs, is this possible?

Comment: Since logstash is ruby based, https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/RedBridge might be helpful for this. As far as I know logstash artifacts are not published in Maven repository, so you will need to add them directly from the source.